# Faster to insert new records, or update a pre-loaded table

Tags: t-sql, transactions, insert, try-catch

I have an MS SQL table that has a compound primary key of two integer values, and another field to indicate the session associated with that record. Let's call these PKs "location" and "item", and the associated value as "shopper". Each location has 1000+ items, and each item can be selected by exactly one shopper.

At the moment when a request is made by a shopper, I attempt to insert into that table with location, item, and shopper. The result I return is based on whether or not the insert throws a primary key error.

To give you an idea of the volume, there might be 200 shoppers contending for 1000 items at a single location. Each shopper can make a request about every 1.5 seconds or so. I have approximately 10 busy locations open at any one time. As the moment the table with locations/items has just under 1 million records in it.

So, my questions are these:

1. Is it ok to attempt the insert then catch the thrown error (as I'm doing now), or would it be better to use a transaction an then do an exists prior to the insert?

EXAMPLE WITH INSERT

```
BEGIN TRY  
  INSERT INTO table
  (
      location
    , item
    , shopper
  )
  VALUES
  (
      @location
    , @item
    , @shopper
  )
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
  -- The insert failed, which means that another shopper
  -- has already claimed this item. Respond accordingly
END CATCH
```

EXAMPLE WITH EXISTS/INSERT

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM table 
      WHERE location = @location
        AND item = @item
    )
    INSERT INTO table
    (
        location
      , item
      , shopper
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @location
      , @item
      , @shopper
    )
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      -- "Insert" was not successful, handle appropriately
    END
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

2. Would it be faster to create empty records for each item and then do updates (with appropriate WHERE clauses to make sure another shopper isn't bumped). In this instance I know for sure that a subsequent read would be necessary to see if the update was successful.

EXAMPLE

```
UPDATE table
SET shopper = @shopper
WHERE location = @location
  AND item = @item
  AND shopper IS NULL

-- Check to see if the update was successful

IF @shopper = (SELECT shopper 
               FROM table
               WHERE location = @location
                 AND item = @item)
BEGIN
  -- Assignment is successful
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- Assignment was unsuccessful
END
```

My understanding is that UPDATES really aren't that much faster than INSERTS because they both create a new row. And in the case of an UPDATE it just marks the original row for deletion.

3. Should I move this part of the system to something like REDIS? Would a hashing platform really provide that large of a boost in performance?

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: How often do you expect an `insert` to fail? 1% of the attempts? 99%?

Comment: Did you consider using `MERGE`?

Comment: During peak traffic, I would expect the `insert` to fail 20% of the time as shoppers all try to grab for the same item.

Comment: I haven't tried `MERGE`, but it's an interesting thought. The data is being added one record at a time as shopper click on items. I will try `MERGE` with an inline select to see if that works, per the example in MS docs. Thank you! But my question still is this... `MERGE` seems to let me atomically branch between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`... but is it really faster to `UPDATE` than `INSERT` in a typical case?

Comment: Some additional reading on [atomic `MERGE`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/02/25/why-is-tsql-merge-failing-with-a-primary-key-violation-isnt-it-atomic/).